# How to access the elements of arrays in a vector in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, indexing, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to find a way in C++ to have a dynamic size array (vector) in which I can store arrays of strings. This concept shall be used to store data with different labels, e.g.:

```
{"Car", "0", "0", "400"},
{"Person", "0", "1", "320"},
{"Bicycle", "1", "0", "300"},
...
```

After a bit internet search, I came this far:

```
struct Stringvec {std::string element[4];};
std::vector<Stringvec> list;
list.push_back({"Car", "0", "0", "400"});
```

But I cannot figure out how to access the individual elements of the arrays I store in the vector, e.g. "Car". This won't work:

```
std::string label = list[0][0]; //Gives error:
error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<Stringvec> >::value_type {aka Stringvec}' and 'int')
```

Anyone knows how to get around this or an even better way to store string arrays in dynamic size arrays?

Comment: Access them using their name `label = list[0].element[0]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `std::array` within `std::vector`

```
vector<array<string, 4>> list = {
    {"Car", "0", "0", "400"},
    {"Bicycle", "1", "2", "500"}
};
```

Then you can access the elements you want to access just like you want:

```
string str = list[0][1];
```

Answer (score -3):

try this
std::string label = list[0].element[0];

Comment: Hi @Beni Efraimov, thanks for your contribution. Because I see you are quite new, let me give you some constructive feedback: 1. The code you suggested doesn't work. Please doublecheck before you post. 2. If you have code in your answer, please format it as such to make it distinguishable from normal text. Thanks!

Comment: Also, if you have code in your answer, be sure to have some normal text explaining why the code is an answer. Code-only answers are typically not useful.